# Webpack: Expose a variable to script-tags

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I am struggeling to make webpack's bundle.js expose the ReactDOM (and probably other variables), to the  tags... Is there a neat trick to this?

I did this with jquery, but is that really the way to go? :

```
$ = require('jquery');
window.jQuery = $;
window.$ = $;
```

Comment: When your application gets split into multiple files/modules, exposing exact components you need to `window.abc` may be the right way. I have seen suggestions not to expose `window` elements unless required.

Answer (score 0):

This is one clean way to do what you want:

Include the script tags for ReactDOM that links to the CDN (or wherever you want to get ReactDOM from) on the output html page:
`<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@15/dist/react-dom.min.js"></script>`

Use the [`externals`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/#externals) property in your webpack config to let webpack now that ReactDOM will come from an external source instead of something that webpack can find in the project directory. In this case, in your `webpack.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  // other configs
  externals: {
   'react-dom': 'ReactDOM'
  }
}
```

The name on the left of the colon is how you reference ReactDOM in your code. The one on the right is what the global variable that the package attaches to `window`.

In your code inside `bundle.js`, `import` ReactDOM as follows:

```
import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
```

In your code outside the bundle, use ReactDOM as a global variable

```
ReactDOM.render(/*some component */)
```

You can generalize this approach to any UMD packages.